# NSDateFormatter cant parse German date

Tags: ios, parsing, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I try to make my `NSDateFormatter` set its locale to German, but it fails. In the code below, while the `dateFrom` is successfully parsed, `dateTo` is not.

> Note: In German it is Februar, not February.

```
NSLocale *germanLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dd. MMMM" options:0
                                                          locale:germanLocale];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:formatString];
NSDate *dateFrom = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"20. September"];
NSDate *dateTo = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"20. Februar"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting locale of NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.locale = germanLocale;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd. MMMM"];
NSDate *dateFrom = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"20. September"];
NSDate *dateTo = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"20. Februar"];
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. but why setting locale in dateFormatFromTemplate function does not work?

Comment: because formatString is just a string, it doesn't contain locale information. Date template can be modified (for example, date components order may be changed according to locale), but still it returns just a string. Please, refer to the documentation of that method - there is an example that show how it woks and what it does.